# 'this' undefined in Reflux.createStore()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, refluxjs, relayjs

I'm trying to set state properties via `this` in my Reflux store, but whenever I attempt to set a property I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'triggers' of undefined`

I've using Babel to compile my JSX, so not sure if that's the issue but I highly doubt it.

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import BoardActions from '../actions/BoardActions';

const BoardStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [BoardActions],
  getInitialState: () => {
    return {
      boards: []
    };
  },
  init: (state = undefined) => {
    if (state) {
      this.state = state;
    }

    this.triggers(this.state);        <-----     Getting the error here
    // this.state = { boards: [] };   <-----     This would also fail
  },

  ...

});
```

And here is the BoardActions:

```
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import BoardSource from '../sources/BoardSource';

const BoardActions = Reflux.createActions({
  'fetch': { children: ['fetching', 'completed', 'failed'] }
});

BoardActions.fetch.listen(() => {
  BoardSource.fetch().then((data) => {
    BoardActions.fetch.completed(data);
  });
});

export default BoardActions;
```

Thanks!

---

### Update

I can see that the transpiler is converting `this` to `undefined` in the compiled code, as below:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _reflux = require('reflux');

var _reflux2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reflux);

var _BoardActions = require('../actions/BoardActions');

var _BoardActions2 = _interopRequireDefault(_BoardActions);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var BoardStore = _reflux2.default.createStore({
  listenables: [_BoardActions2.default],
  init: function init() {
    undefined.test = 'test';
  },
  onFetch: function onFetch() {},
  onFetchFetching: function onFetchFetching() {},
  onFetchCompleted: function onFetchCompleted(boards) {
    undefined.boards = boards;
    undefined.trigger(undefined.boards);
  },
  onFetchFailed: function onFetchFailed() {}
});

exports.default = BoardStore;
//# sourceMappingURL=BoardStore.js.map
```

But still no idea why it would be transpiling `this` to `undefined`.

Comment: Hey man you asked a question about splitting boxes. I did it for you but you removed it... Check this out if it helps cool if not let me know. https://jsfiddle.net/9xyo225z/

Comment: Wow thanks @wuno I'd be more then willing to re-open that question to accept your answer for that. I felt a bit dumb that I didn't add enough detail to the question so that it got so many downvotes so quickly :P, You're answer is great though, I tested with overflowed content and the scrollable areas scroll perfect

Comment: People act like they have never had a question man... Never feel dumb but yes unfortunately people are cruel lol. Ya that would be cool man. then I will delete these comments. Comment when you open it and I will post the link Thanks bro

Comment: Cool, I've undeleted it! I do have an update to the question, which perhaps could be of value to someone in the future (and myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use arrow functions to define your object's methods (for the one you pass to `Reflux.createStore`).

In arrow function `this` is scoped lexically, which means, in the context of your question, that it is `undefined`, since it is lexically bound to the containing module (whatever that is).

See example in [Babel online editor](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20init%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.a%20%3D%20100%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

See more for [further explanation](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/) on cases.

Note: I assume that you are familiar with the basics, otherwise [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html#ch_arrow-functions) is the link to a great article in a great book on ES6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be caused by use of arrow functions.

This should work:

```js
const BoardStore = Reflux.createStore({

  ...

  init(state = undefined) {
    if (state) {
      this.state = state;
    }
    this.triggers(this.state);
    // this.state = { boards: [] };
  },

  ...

});
```